# Some UIColors are black instead of the way the way they should be, why?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I'm making this app and let's say I get the CGFloat values for red, green and blue for an rgba color. I use them to give colors to cells in a tableView. Some work just fine, but some are black instead of the color they should be. It's mainly dark colors, although I highly doubt that has anything to do with it. I don't know why this is happening.

Here's the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.cellColor.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(myClasses[indexPath.row].red), green: CGFloat(myClasses[indexPath.row].green), blue: CGFloat(myClasses[indexPath.row].blue), alpha: 1.0)
    cell.cellLabel.text = myClasses[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
```

Some examples:

```
case "Light green":
        colorArray = [128/255, 1, 0]
    case "Dark green":
        colorArray = [76/255, 153/255, 0]
    case "Light blue":
        colorArray = [0, 1, 1]
    case "Dark blue":
        colorArray = [51/255, 51/255, 1]
    case "Purple":
        colorArray = [102/255, 0, 204/255]
    case "Yellow":
        colorArray = [1, 1, 0]
```

Light green, light blue and yellow work. Dark green, dark blue and purple don't.

Comment: Why are you using these color arrays? Seems like an odd way to do it.

Comment: I know. There's more to it. This is the best way.

Comment: At least, I think  it is.

Comment: What is the type defined on `colorArray`? 
It would be easier to just return a `UIColor` initialized via the rgb initializer directly.

Comment: + does your switch have a `default` case…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`76/255`, `153/255`, `102/255` and `204/255` is integer division, and all equal `0`.

To solve this just make either the numerator or the denominator double by adding `.0`:

`76/255.0`, `76.0/255.0` or `76.0/255.0`

You should make sure it is *real* division for all other colors too.

Answer (score 1):

The is that dividing two `Int`s results in another `Int`, while you need a `Double`. Convert them to `CGFloat`, since the `UIColor` initializer accepts `CGFloat`s anyways. Also define `colorArray` as `[CGFloat]`.

```
case "Light green":
    colorArray = [CGFloat(128)/CGFloat(255), 1, 0]
case "Dark green":
    colorArray = [CGFloat(76)/CGFloat(255), CGFloat(153)/CGFloat(255), 0]
case "Light blue":
    colorArray = [0, 1, 1]
case "Dark blue":
    colorArray = [CGFloat(51)/CGFloat(255), CGFloat(51)/CGFloat(255), 1]
case "Purple":
    colorArray = [CGFloat(102)/CGFloat(255), 0, CGFloat(204)/CGFloat(255)]
case "Yellow":
    colorArray = [1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As implied in other answers, Swift type inference doesn't know those arrays should have type `CGFloat`. If you did, for example, `let foo: CGFloat = 123/255` then that would not be integer division. But the types of those array components are inferred to still be `Int`. So you're getting black because any division less than 1 will be floored to 0.

If you must, for whatever reason, use this setup you've defined in your question, you can use a tuple instead of an array:

```
typealias ColorTuple = (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat)

// ...
var colorTuple: ColorTuple?
let myColor = "Light green" // for example

switch myColor {
case "Light green":
    colorTuple = (128/255, 1, 0)
case "Dark green":
    colorTuple = (76/255, 153/255, 0)
case "Light blue":
    colorTuple = (0, 1, 1)
case "Dark blue":
    colorTuple = (51/255, 51/255, 1)
case "Purple":
    colorTuple = (102/255, 0, 204/255)
case "Yellow":
    colorTuple = (1, 1, 0)
default:
    break
}
```

This has the advantage of being much more concise than the other suggestions. If you need it to be an array you could create an appropriate array afterwards.

Hard to say without knowing more, but you may find that using an extension on `UIColor` with static vars named `lightGreen`, `darkGreen` etc that return `UIColor` instances initialized using the RGB initializer would be better than what you have here.